# Unable to insert data to mongodb using express

Tags: mongodb, express

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const mongodb = require('mongodb');

    const app = express();
    app.use(cors())
    app.use(bodyParser.json());


    const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/recart";


    const InsertOne = () => {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("mydb");
            var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
            dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 document inserted");
            db.close();
            });
        });
    }




    app.get("/" , (req, res) => {
        InsertOne()
        res.send('hello')
    })

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=> {
        console.log(`App is running on port 3000`);
    })
```

Here i am tring to insert document into my mongodb using nodejs

In console it is showing "1 document inserted" but when i check the db nothing is there

Please have a look

Comment: Have you checked the `customers` collection in both the `recart` and `mydb` databases?

Comment: when i copy/pasted your code into my own editor everything seems to work fine, are you it is not inserted?

Answer (score 0):

The data is inserted properly. Type the following thing to check into MongoDB. In your terminal type:

1. `mongo`
2. `use mydb`
3. `db.customers.find().pretty()`

[image: I found the data properly]